# Integrating COUNT() into a nested MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following nested MYSQL query. Currently, out of the results, I go through and tally the tag appearances to identify the frequency. I've tried to integrate MYSQL's COUNT() into my query but have been unable to.

Current query:

```
SELECT tagId 
FROM refTags 
WHERE postId IN (SELECT postId FROM refTags WHERE tagId = 1) 
AND tagId <> 1
ORDER BY tagId ASC
```

The desired return is tagId, COUNT(tagId) sorted by COUNT(tagId) DESC.

Am I able to do this all in the same query or am I correct in doing the counting after the results return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one result row per tag ID, so group by tag ID. Then count.

```
SELECT tagId, COUNT(*) AS number_of_posts
FROM refTags 
WHERE postId IN (SELECT postId FROM refTags WHERE tagId = 1)
AND tagId <> 1 
GROUP BY tagId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Cheers! That works perfectly. I appreciate your help.